# How to rollback to previous kernel in Fedora when new update shows blank screen at boot?

Tags: fedora, kernel, upgrade, dnf

In fedora 37 I did

`sudo dnf -y update`

It updated the packages and kernel. But I remember that **I didn't reboot the system after that**. I just powered it off.

The next day, the boot menu showed the multiple entries as it supposed to. I chose the first as its the latest default. But then my screen gone black with a blinking cursor at corner.

I rebooted the system by pressing CTRL + ALT + Del and then chose 2nd boot entry this time, and I am able to boot into that.

Now, to revert the latest update changes I tried

`sudo dnf history undo 23`

It produced output as follows:

```
Error: The following problems occurred while running a transaction:
  Cannot find rpm nevra "fwupd-1.8.12-1.fc37.x86_64".
  Cannot find rpm nevra "fwupd-plugin-flashrom-1.8.12-1.fc37.x86_64".
  Cannot find rpm nevra "fwupd-plugin-modem-manager-1.8.12-1.fc37.x86_64".
  Cannot find rpm nevra "fwupd-plugin-uefi-capsule-data-1.8.12-1.fc37.x86_64".
  Cannot find rpm nevra "gnome-maps-43.4-1.fc37.x86_64".
  Cannot find rpm nevra "gnome-shell-43.3-1.fc37.x86_64".
  Cannot find rpm nevra "gvfs-1.50.3-1.fc37.x86_64".
  Cannot find rpm nevra "gvfs-afc-1.50.3-1.fc37.x86_64".
  Cannot find rpm nevra "gvfs-afp-1.50.3-1.fc37.x86_64".
  Cannot find rpm nevra "gvfs-archive-1.50.3-1.fc37.x86_64".
  Cannot find rpm nevra "gvfs-client-1.50.3-1.fc37.x86_64".
  Cannot find rpm nevra "gvfs-fuse-1.50.3-1.fc37.x86_64".
  Cannot find rpm nevra "gvfs-goa-1.50.3-1.fc37.x86_64".
  Cannot find rpm nevra "gvfs-gphoto2-1.50.3-1.fc37.x86_64".
  Cannot find rpm nevra "gvfs-mtp-1.50.3-1.fc37.x86_64".
  Cannot find rpm nevra "gvfs-smb-1.50.3-1.fc37.x86_64".
  Cannot find rpm nevra "libsemanage-3.5-1.fc37.x86_64".
  Cannot find rpm nevra "mutter-43.3-2.fc37.x86_64".
  Cannot find rpm nevra "python3-libsemanage-3.5-1.fc37.x86_64".
  Cannot find rpm nevra "tigervnc-license-1.13.1-1.fc37.noarch".
  Cannot find rpm nevra "tigervnc-server-minimal-1.13.1-1.fc37.x86_64".
  Cannot find rpm nevra "webp-pixbuf-loader-0.2.2-1.fc37.x86_64".
  Cannot find rpm nevra "kernel-6.1.14-200.fc37.x86_64".
  Cannot find rpm nevra "kernel-core-6.1.14-200.fc37.x86_64".
  Cannot find rpm nevra "kernel-modules-6.1.14-200.fc37.x86_64".
```

I also tried

`sudo dnf history rollback 23`

But it gave me following output

```
Transaction history is incomplete, before 25
Transaction history is incomplete, before 25
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
```